# How can I calculate a time difference with the server time?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using opencart and want to display text (product ending time) like this:
    end in 09 dys 12 hours 30 Mins

I have an `ends_date` from the table but now I want to calculate the time difference between `ends_date` and the server time and display in the above format, in PHP or jQuery.

Thanks!

Comment: What does ends_date look like ? and what did googling "date difference php" or "date difference jquery" return ? what have you tried already ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$current_time = time();
$end_time = strtotime($ends_date); //$ends_date is from your table
$time_diff = $end_time - $current_time;
```

From there you have `$time_diff` that represents the number of seconds till it's over. Do some / 60 for minutes and then hours and then / 24 for days. Make sure you only do that if $time_diff > 0! Math. It works. :)

Comment: thanks vary much, but can you please write a code to format the time $time_diff in above format.

Comment: This isn't 'do the work for you', but the forum is about pointing you in the right direction. If you can't do the follow-up simple math, I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(ends_date, now())
FROM yourtable
```

docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).